# Xcode load slow things after the View is visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, loading

I have a very annoying problem. I have a ViewController with an UIImageView in it. The UIImageView should display a slide show. The images for the are coming from NSURL, so it takes a bit of time.

`- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadImages];
}`

This is how I get the Images from the NSURL. The problem I have is, that while the Images are loading I only see a black screen.
At the beginning and at the end of the `-(void)loadImages`  method I implemented a UIActivityIndicator to display the loading time.
I already tried `-(void)viewWillAppear` and `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews` but nothing worked.

Thanks for help
Jannes

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is load your images asynchronously and populate them as they come in (with delegate or block callbacks, depending on the API you use). You should absolutely *never* run networking code, or any other potentially long-running operation, synchronously on the main thread. The reason for this is that the UI runs on the main thread, so if you block it with your own operations, the UI cannot update and your app will become unresponsive.

Whether you're using Apple's networking frameworks or something like AFNetworking (highly recommended), there are many ways to do networking asynchronously with minimal work.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably downloading your images synchronously.  Try wrapping it in a `dispatch_async` block to run it on a different thread.

Example:

```
-(void)loadImages {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {

        // download the images here

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {

            // update the UI on the main thread

        });

    });

}
```

Check out the `SDWebImage` library as well as most of this heavy lifting is done for you.

Comment: You should accept his answer if it solved your problem.